# Upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)

Tags: 8

I installed [opigno_lms 8.x-2.9](https://drupal.org/project/opigno_lms), I created a training and want to publish it. When I click "Publish", the site try to load for 60 seconds and then get "Error 504: Gateway time-out". In nginx error log: "[error] upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream"

I modified `php.ini`:

```
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600
```

and added below to nginx conf file, `server` context:

```
proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
```

Also added below to druapl `setting.php`:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
ini_set('max_input_time', 3600);
```

But still the site try for 60 seconds and give same error. I think I'm missing a configuration somewhere that still effective and timeout the site connection in 60 seconds. Thanks to advice.

**Site information**:

- Drupal version: 8.9.20
- Installation profile: Opigno LMS (opigno_lms-8.x-2.29)
- PHP version: 7.4.29

  - memory_limit = 512M
- Web server: nginx/1.18.0

Comment: I m curious as to why you are testing an Opigno LMS version that is not supported by its maintainers.

Comment: Have you confirmed the PHP settings are updated?

Comment: I don't think this issue related to opigno lms in particular, but to answer your question, basically because the current opigno lms version is not working with me due to this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno_lms/issues/3278953)

Comment: @HarishST: good question, yes I confirmed that using `phpinfo();`

Comment: Try setting `fastcgi_send_timeout` and `fastcgi_read_timeout` along with the proxy settings (and restart/reload nginx). You may also/alternatively need to set `request_terminate_timeout` in PHP-FPM config

Comment: Thanks @Clive: it seems that original issue (error 504) resolved after adding `request_terminate_timeout = 0` in php-fpm pool config and ```fastcgi_connect_timeout 3600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600s``` in nginx config, server context. Now I'm getting `Error 524 A timeout occurred` which is related to CloudFlare which by default timeout after 100 seconds. I'll check what can be done with the new error.